# Finding min and max of a point vector

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to find the min and max value from a point vector. The vector consists of x and y element type. I want the min and max of x and the minmax of y. My vector is defined as:

```
 std::vector<cv::Point> location;
findNOZeroInMat(angles,location);

//I tried to use but it gives an error
  minMaxLoc(location.cols(0), &minVal_x, &maxVal_x);
    minMaxLoc(location.cols(1), &minVal_y, &maxVal_y);
```

I tried location.x too but it didn't work. How  can I get the min and max value of x and y seperately?

Comment: `std::partial_sort` with custom comparators.

Comment: You mean sorting the vector and taking the first element as min and max?

Comment: Partially sorting the vector, yes.

Comment: Okay but how can I sort x and y seperately? How can I get x and y from the location vector like location.x or something??

Comment: See my answer. You don't need to sort the vector.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [std::minmax_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) with custom less-than comparison functions/functors:

```
#include <algorithm>

bool less_by_x(const cv::Point& lhs, const cv::Point& rhs)
{
  return lhs.x < rhs.x;
}
```

Then

```
auto mmx = std::minmax_element(location.begin(), location.end(), less_by_x);
```

and similarly for `y`. `mmx.first` will have an iterator to the minimum element, and `mmx.second` to the maximum one.

If you don't have C++11 support for `auto` you need to be explicit:

```
typedef std::vector<cv::Point>::const_iterator PointIt;
std::pair<PointIt, PointIt> mmx = std::minmax_element(location.begin(), 
                                                      location.end(), 
                                                      less_by_x);
```

but note that `std::minmax_element` requires C++11 library support.

Comment: When i use this    auto mm = minmax_element(location.begin(), location.end(), less_by_x);
    auto mmy = minmax_element(location.begin(), location.end(), less_by_y); I get an error mm and mmy does not have a  name type

    cout<<"min_x"<<mm.first<<"max_x"<<mm.second<<"min_y"<<mmy.first<<"max_y"<<mmy.second<<endl;

Comment: @user1583647 Do you have C++11 support for `auto`? Otherwise you need to be explicit. I will add an example.

Answer (score 4):

[`cv::boundingRect`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gacb413ddce8e48ff3ca61ed7cf626a366) is doing what you want. It

> Calculates the up-right bounding rectangle of a point set.

The result is of type [`cv::Rect`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/d44/classcv_1_1Rect__.html#details) which has attributes `x, y, width, heigth` but also provides methods `tl` (= top left corner) and `br` (= bottom right corner) which can be used to find desired min. and max. values. Note that `tl` is inclusive but `bt` is exclusive.

```
std::vector<cv::Point> points;
// do something to fill points...

cv::Rect rect = cv::boundingRect(points);

// tl() directly equals to the desired min. values
cv::Point minVal = rect.tl();

// br() is exclusive so we need to subtract 1 to get the max. values
cv::Point maxVal = rect.br() - cv::Point(1, 1);
```